# Prevent user from Logout in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is a login url

```
http://localhost:4200/login
```

After a successful login the user is redirected to

```
http://localhost:4200/account
```

Clicking the browser "back button" redirect the user back to login.
I would like to prevent this and show the user alert box with a confirmation button.
I can think of multiple ways to achieve it but I'm not sure which one is the best.

1. router.events observable
2. @HostListener
3. guards (not very sure about this one)

here is an example using router.events

```
this.router.events.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.onDestroy),
    filter((event: RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationStart),
    tap(() =>  {

        if (this.router.url === 'login') {

           // alert box
        }

).subscribe();
```

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**
please have a look at @vijay comment

Comment: Use browser local storage to save your login state and every time when you redirect to main or app component... In angular OnInit check weather your session is expired or not.... If not then rediect to your desired component else to login component...

Comment: so simple and smart, thank you @vijay !!!